# Knockout.js: push item -> specify the new DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, knockout.js

I have a list of people on my view, looking like this:
Their name is not editable (the list is loaded via ajax and I only want new entries to be editable)

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
    <tr>
        <td><input data-bind='text: name' readonly="readonly"
            class="form-control input-sm" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

then I have a button to add new elements:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-bind='click: addPerson'>
    Add
</button>
```

And my view Model:

```
function PeopleViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addPerson = function() {
        self.people.push({
            name: ""
        });
    };      
}

function Person(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}
```

How can I specify my DOM element in the function `"addPerson"` so that the DOM elements I add are not `readonly="readonly"`, is that possible with Knockout?

Thanks - James

Comment: Your model and HTML should be separate. `AddPerson` should **not** explicitly create DOM elements. Add a `readonly` boolean to the `Person` object and bind it to the `readonly` attribute in the DOM. Then when adding a new `Person` object to the array set the `readonly` boolean `false` and knockout will render the DOM as required. Also your `addPerson` should either create a new instance of `Person` and push that into the array or take an instance of a new `Person` as a parameter.

Comment: They are seperated, just put it together to keep it smaller for StackOverflow. Thanks for the idea, will give it a try right ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your `Peron` model with a `writable` property:

```
function Person(name, writable) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.writable= ko.observable(writable || false);
}
```

Then when adding a person, set it to `true`:

```
self.addPerson = function() {
    self.people.push(new Person("", true));
};
```

And when rendering your HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: name, attr: { readonly: !writable() }"
       class="form-control input-sm" type="text" />
```

(Please note that I changed the binding-handler from `text` to `value`)